# VPC and NACL configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, acl, vpc

I have a QA instance in a VPC-appsubnet. My VPC has a NACL different from subnets NACL. Does this cause any issue accessing my QA Instance?

Answer (score 0):

A Network ACL in AWS is an object that can created inside a VPC, and can be attached to Subnet objects.

So in a nutshell, a NACL belongs to a VPC but is associated with subnet/s.

See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#ACLs).

Answer (score 0):

Network ACL for your VPC is at Subnet level. VPC can have multiple subnets, so there can be multiple NACL associated with the VPC.

If there are issues accessing an instance and you're concerned about the Network ACL rules, you can check the Network ACL associated with the subnet in which the instance is. Also, you could check the VPC configuration.